# Cannot use imported classes methods with cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

There is a problem, I just installed cocos2d for iPhone.
The first problem was that it wasn't recognizing any header like CCDirectory.h for example.
So I turned on user search paths in the project, but this way I could just import the header and have an object pointer without getting any warning, but methods aren't recognized.
It's hard to explain, so see this code:

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CCMenuItem.h>
#import <cocos2d.h>
```

Inside applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
CCMenuItem* item; // This does not give a warning, except for the "unused variable"
                  // But the class is recognized

[CCMenuItem setFontName: @""]; // Warning
```

The warning is:

```
Class method '+setFontName:' not found (return type default to 'id')
```

And it doesn't recognize any other method, just NSObject's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the methods you are calling exists in that class? CCMenuItem doesn't contain a static method named setFontName. Try changing CCMenuItem to CCMenuItemFont.

```
[CCMenuItemFont setFontName: @""];
```